# Problem in NGINX + Gzip compress on Json Data - Project NodeJS/Express

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, gzip

I have a problem on my project, when I try to activate Gzip on application/json I got a encoded JSON, but when I remove it everything is working fine

Is there any idea how to solve it?

This is the Gzip configuration
``
gzip on;

```
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;

    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/svg+xml;
```

``

the project developed by NodeJs and Express

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advace!

Comment: are you using app.use(compression()) any where in your code? remove that nginx will handle it for you.

Answer (score 0):

2 things to try here,

1. Removing `app.use(express.static('public'))` and `app.use(compression())` if you have in your application.
2. gzip_types should match the following

```
gzip_types
    text/css
    text/plain
    text/javascript
    application/javascript
    application/json
    application/x-javascript
    application/xml
    application/xml+rss
    application/xhtml+xml
    application/x-font-ttf
    application/x-font-opentype
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    image/svg+xml
    image/x-icon
    application/rss+xml
    application/atom_xml
```